# if statement inside while loop. Why is it doing this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, while-loop

I am using this:

```
//if in landscape mode
while(window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
                    if(!$('#page' + hiddenNextPage).hasClass('showUp')) {
                        $('#page' + hiddenNextPage).addClass('showUp');
                        $('#page' + hiddenNextPage).css('margin-left', '300px');
                    };
                }

//if in portrait mode
while(window.orientation == 0) {
                    if($('#page' + hiddenNextPage).hasClass('showUp')) {
                        $('#page' + hiddenNextPage).removeClass('showUp');
                        $('#page' + hiddenNextPage).css('margin-left', '5px');
                    };
                };
```

But its making my pages not even load anymore.. & it takes such a long time to load this. Is there anything wrong with it?

Is there a better way of constantly checking if the orientation has been changed without using a while loop?

This is for the ipad/iphone
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're only changing styles, you could use separate stylesheets for portrait and landscape...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```

**EDIT**

There's also an `onorientationchange` event on `window` which allows you to run code when the orientation changes rather than constantly polling for a change...

```
window.onorientationchange = function (event)
{
    if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using that also, but in landscape mode I need a completely new div inserted. 

Soo I need to find some way with javascript/jquery. There will also be a lot of changes to the original code after wards.

Comment: Thank you that seems perfect! ill try it out now

Answer (score 6):

I don't see that the bodies of your while loops are modifying the while tests. This produces an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I want an infinite loop.
I need it to continue checking it to see if it has been changed.

Comment: The result of the test will change when the orientation of the device changes, so the apparently infinite loop is a deliberate way to wait for the change of orientation. However, it's also the cause of the slow loading problem since it will consume 100% CPU constantly testing for a change.

Comment: There's a really big difference between an actual "infinite loop", in programmatic terms, and a "periodic algorithm, executed indefinitely".  What you have in your code above is the former (which will lock the browser), and what you need is the latter - of which several SOers have offered solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using stevemegson's way it was much easier.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should be using a while loop at all.

If you want to execute code periodically, use a timeout or interval.

Also, your jQuery is very inefficient - especially with how you re-run the selector so many times.

```
var $nextPage = $('#page' + hiddenNextPage );

window.setInterval( function()
{
  if ( 0 == window.orientation )
  {
    if ( $nextPage.hasClass( 'showUp' ) )
    {
      $nextPage
        .removeClass( 'showUp' )
        .css( 'margin-left', '5px' )
      ;
    }
  }
  else if ( !$nextPage.hasClass( 'showUp' ) )
  {
    $nextPage
      .addClass( 'showUp' )
      .css( 'margin-left', '300px' )
    ;
  }
}, 100 ); // 100 means this will execute every 100 milliseconds
```

Comment: Oh, i only repeated it to make it more simple to read instead of putting it all in one big line. I didn't know i could do it the way you just did though! thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend seperate style sheets, but as far your question of constantly checking you can set a timeout with `setInterval ( expression, interval );`

example:

```
setInterval(function() {
   if ((window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
      if(!$('#page' + hiddenNextPage).hasClass('showUp')) {
         $('#page' + hiddenNextPage).addClass('showUp');
         $('#page' + hiddenNextPage).css('margin-left', '300px');
      }
   } else if (window.orientation == 0) {
      if($('#page' + hiddenNextPage).hasClass('showUp')) {
         $('#page' + hiddenNextPage).removeClass('showUp');
         $('#page' + hiddenNextPage).css('margin-left', '5px');
      }
   }
}
, 2000 );
```

**edit** Accidently used setTimeout instead of setInterval the first time, oops.

Comment: I think you mean `setInterval`